# Balanced-parentheses problem: match function parameters

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a PCRE regex to match a particular balanced-parentheses situation, and while I've looked at a bunch of discussions of the problem (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)), I can't get anything to work. I'm trying to use regex101.com to debug.

I'm trying to match a string like `foo` inside `MyFunction(foo)`, where `foo` can be anything, including other function calls that can themselves contain parentheses. That is, I want to be able to match

```
MyFunction(23)
MyFunction('Sekret')
MyFunction( 23, 'Sekret', Date() )
MyFunction( Encrypt('Sekret'), Date() )
```

But MyFunction can be part of a larger string which itself can have parentheses, e.g.

```
logger.info("MyFunction( Encrypt('Sekret'), Date() )")
```

in which case I want only what is passed to MyFunction to be matched, not what is passed to logger.info.

The purpose of this is to replace whatever is passed to MyFunction with something else, e.g. "XXXXXX".

Using a regex from the linked question (e.g. `\((?:[^)(]+|(?R))*+\)`) will match the outermost set of parens, but if I try to preface it with `MyFunction`—i.e. if I try the regex `MyFunction\((?:[^)(]+|(?R))*+\)`—it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex: `MyFunction(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\))`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/OS9XHh/1)

updated regex , supports PCRE.

`MyFunction\((?:[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))*[^()]*)*\)`

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/Xi7KNO/1)

updated again regex, supports nested function

`MyFunction\(((?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*)\)`

[demo3](https://regex101.com/r/99nc6M/1)

Comment: Yikes, I can't even begin to grok that! Unfortunately, while it works for your demo, it's not a PCRE regex as requested, so it fails for my use case.

Comment: Nice approach, but it will fail for a nested function call such as `MyFunction(foo(bar(baz)))`.

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try:

```
(?<=MyFunction\()([^()]+|\((?1)*\))+(?=\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o1euNP/1)

- `(?<=MyFunction\()` is a positive lookbehind assertion to match the string
  `MyFunction(` without including the match in the capture group.
- `([^()]+|\((?1)*\))` is the alternation of `[^()]+` or `\((?1)*\)`. The former
  matches a sequence of characters other than `(` and `)`. The latter recursively
  matches a parenthesized string, where `(?1)` is the partial recursion of the capture
  group 1.
- The final `(?=\))` is a positive lookahead assertion to match the right paren `)`
  to make a pair with `MyFunction(`.